# Deleting records from Salesforce via Mulesoft ESB

Tags: salesforce, mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-el

I am trying to delete list of records from Salesforce via Mulesoft ESB.
I have already create an example project on github and the flow xml can be found [here](https://github.com/sumveds/tutorial/blob/master/src/main/app/tutorial.xml).

The xml snippet for deleting records is below:

```
<sfdc:delete config-ref="Salesforce__Basic_authentication" doc:name="Salesforce">
            <sfdc:ids ref="#[payload]" />
        </sfdc:delete>
```

where, payload data type is List of string.

While deleting the records I am getting below exception:

```
    ERROR 2015-11-05 23:39:39,755 [[tutorial].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.01] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Could not serialize object (org.mule.api.serialization.SerializationException)
Type                  : org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
JavaDoc               : http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transformer/TransformerException.html
Transformer           : ObjectToByteArray{this=7be7e15, name='_ObjectToByteArray', ignoreBadInput=false, returnClass=SimpleDataType{type=[B, mimeType='*/*', encoding='null'}, sourceTypes=[SimpleDataType{type=java.io.Serializable, mimeType='*/*', encoding='null'}, SimpleDataType{type=java.io.InputStream, mimeType='*/*', encoding='null'}, SimpleDataType{type=java.lang.String, mimeType='*/*', encoding='null'}, SimpleDataType{type=org.mule.api.transport.OutputHandler, mimeType='*/*', encoding='null'}]}
********************************************************************************
Exception stack is:
1. com.sforce.soap.partner.DeleteResult (java.io.NotSerializableException)
  java.io.ObjectOutputStream:1184 (null)
2. java.io.NotSerializableException: com.sforce.soap.partner.DeleteResult (org.apache.commons.lang.SerializationException)
  org.apache.commons.lang.SerializationUtils:111 (null)
3. Could not serialize object (org.mule.api.serialization.SerializationException)
  org.mule.serialization.internal.AbstractObjectSerializer:68 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/serialization/SerializationException.html)
4. Could not serialize object (org.mule.api.serialization.SerializationException) (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException)
  org.mule.transformer.simple.SerializableToByteArray:66 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transformer/TransformerException.html)
********************************************************************************
Root Exception stack trace:
java.io.NotSerializableException: com.sforce.soap.partner.DeleteResult
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1378)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at org.apache.commons.lang.SerializationUtils.serialize(SerializationUtils.java:108)
    at org.apache.commons.lang.SerializationUtils.serialize(SerializationUtils.java:133)
    at org.mule.serialization.internal.JavaObjectSerializer.doSerialize(JavaObjectSerializer.java:44)
    at org.mule.serialization.internal.AbstractObjectSerializer.serialize(AbstractObjectSerializer.java:64)
    at org.mule.transformer.simple.SerializableToByteArray.doTransform(SerializableToByteArray.java:62)
    at org.mule.transformer.simple.ObjectToByteArray.doTransform(ObjectToByteArray.java:78)
    at org.mule.transformer.AbstractTransformer.transform(AbstractTransformer.java:415)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.getPayload(DefaultMuleMessage.java:425)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.getPayload(DefaultMuleMessage.java:373)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.getPayloadAsBytes(DefaultMuleMessage.java:714)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.HttpResponseBuilder.build(HttpResponseBuilder.java:175)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.HttpMessageProcessorTemplate.sendResponseToClient(HttpMessageProcessorTemplate.java:97)
    at org.mule.execution.AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase.runPhase(AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase.java:83)
    at org.mule.execution.AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase.runPhase(AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase.java:38)
    at org.mule.execution.PhaseExecutionEngine$InternalPhaseExecutionEngine.phaseSuccessfully(PhaseExecutionEngine.java:65)
    at org.mule.execution.PhaseExecutionEngine$InternalPhaseExecutionEngine.phaseSuccessfully(PhaseExecutionEngine.java:69)
    at com.mulesoft.mule.throttling.ThrottlingPhase.runPhase(ThrottlingPhase.java:185)
    at com.mulesoft.mule.throttling.ThrottlingPhase.runPhase(ThrottlingPhase.java:1)
    at org.mule.execution.PhaseExecutionEngine$InternalPhaseExecutionEngine.process(PhaseExecutionEngine.java:114)
    at org.mule.execution.PhaseExecutionEngine.process(PhaseExecutionEngine.java:41)
    at org.mule.execution.MuleMessageProcessingManager.processMessage(MuleMessageProcessingManager.java:32)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.DefaultHttpListener$1.handleRequest(DefaultHttpListener.java:126)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.GrizzlyRequestDispatcherFilter.handleRead(GrizzlyRequestDispatcherFilter.java:83)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.run0(ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.java:102)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.access$100(ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.java:30)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.java:125)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually deleting successfully. The problem is that your Mule flow ends after making the Salesforce call, and by default it tries to return the current payload. That payload is the result of the SF call, which is of type com.sforce.soap.partner.DeleteResult, and Mule doesn't know how to serialize it.

To start, try simply adding a "Set payload" component after the SF call and set payload to anything you want, say "hello world". Once you understand what's happening, you can add a groovy script to process the DeleteResult and actually determine if the deletion was successful or not, and possibly do something if it wasn't.

Comment: Thanks Egor! You are right. That was the reason. :)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, if you don't want to explicitly change the payload and want the exact payload being sent out of the SFDC connector, then try having an object to json connector after the sfdc connector and a logger to log the payload in this case.