# deleting data from SalesForce using MuleSoft Anypoint

Tags: salesforce, mule-studio, mule-el, anypoint-studio

I've created this sample workflow in mulesoft that is suppose to delete a SalesForce lead based on the id i provided it. Whenever I run the flow I keep getting the error below. Am I formatting the payload correctly?

```
ERROR 2016-04-19 20:16:18,773 [[deleteit].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.01] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy:
********************************************************************************
Message               : Could not find a transformer to transform
"SimpleDataType{type=java.util.LinkedHashMap, mimeType='*/*', encoding='null'}" to "CollectionDataType{type=java.util.List, itemType=java.lang.Object, mimeType='*/*'}".
Type                  : org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException
Code                  : MULE_ERROR-236
JavaDoc               : http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transformer/TransformerException.html
********************************************************************************
```

**This is my workflow:**

[image]

**This is what's in my Message Transform:**

[image]

**My SalesForce connector's Delete Config:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. 
Instead of using

```
{id:'somesalesforce id'}
```

in the message transform format it as such:

```
['somesalesforce id','another salesforce id']
```

This did delete the data salesforce but gave me another error message. I guess it's still some success since I can delete it from SalesForce.

Error message received:

```
Could not serialize object (org.mule.api.serialization.SerializationException)
```

Comment: Apparently the the above error was thrown because Mule doesn't know how to interpret the response returned from SalesForce. So it you just get a payload after the SalesForce call, the error goes away. For more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33551834/deleting-records-from-salesforce-via-mulesoft-esb

Answer (score 0):

If you use the component Salesforce, you will set the following parameters into connector configuration:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1Yxz.gif)

Best Regards,
Giuseppe.

Answer (score 0):

The delete feature of Salesforce connector requires an ArrayList and not a hashmap. As correctly mentioned in 1 of the answers, you can send an arraylist of ids of records you want to delete in salesforce. 
You can find a detailed reference of all operations with salesforce connector at https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/salesforce-connector-reference

This reference is super helpful for all salesforce related operations and configurations.

HTH